# Import JSON into Core Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated
In this tutorial show how build a script for create a sqlite and import data from json.
I have write this:

```
static NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel()
{
    static NSManagedObjectModel *model = nil;

    if (model != nil) {
        return model;
    }
    NSString *path = @"AppChecker";
    path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mom"]];
    model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];        
    return model;
}

static NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext()
{
    static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;

    if (context != nil) {
        return context;
    }
    @autoreleasepool {
        context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel()];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

        NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

        NSString *path = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments][0];
        path = [path stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];
        NSError *error;
        NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:nil error:&error];
        if (newStore == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
        }
    }
    return context;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();

        // Custom code here...
        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        NSError* err = nil;
        NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brands" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* Brands = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&err];
        NSLog(@"Imported Brands: %@", Brands);

        NSString* dataPath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"products" ofType:@"json"];
        NSArray* Products = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath2]
                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                            error:&err];
        NSLog(@"Imported Products: %@", Products);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, it create the .sqlite database(and structure is ok), but there isn't data!!!

My db is so:

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/470h0d0F2S3j1n2N2R35/screeen.png]

And this is my json of brands for example:

```
[{
"id":"1",
"name":"TestBrand",
"description":"",
"website":"",
"email":"",
"address":"",
"phone":"",
"from_country_list":"CZ",
"created_at":"2013-11-24 11:51:17.363473",
"updated_at":"2013-11-24 11:51:17.363473"
}]
```

Any help/tips on why the data isn't imported in .sqlite db ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that you are only half-way through the tutorial. The part where the JSON data is put into the Core Data store is missing completely in your code. In the tutorial that is the `[Banks enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:..` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue with the tutorial. You will have to iterate through your objects created from the JSON files and add each instance to the Core Data object graph, populate it with the available attributes and finally `save` the context.

Only after this last step will the data be stored in the sqlite database.

Comment: LOL, i need more sleep...thank you.(and i lost also many time in checking database etc...).